# API to query ME, BE/ME, P/E etc. accounting data per stock symbol

Tags: programming, data, market-data, historical-data

We **don't** have access to:

1. Bloomberg
2. Thomson Reuters
3. CRSP
4. COMPUSTAT

And we are trying to replicate FF-1992, so we can have stocks returns via yahoo finance, like: http://investexcel.net/multiple-stock-quote-downloader-for-excel/

The question: How in similar way we can have all other data like ME, BE/ME, P/E and other accounting data? We need some API or similar automated tool to the Excel linked above - Where the ability to perform in single click operation on multiple stocks is very useful.

Thanks,

Comment: I think, you're asking for too much :)

Comment: Why? What is too much? In 2016 it ahould be obvious.

Comment: Because, otherwise the above mentioned companies wouldn't be selling their data for money, maybe?